# Change of Security Stamp

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core

When a user's password is updated I want the Security stamp value to be updated every time that happens. I believe that is how Security stamp works from my research.

I place this code in the `ApplicationUserManager.cs` but this isn't working:

```
 private static string NewSecurityStamp()
 {
     return Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
 }
```

What and where do I need to get the security stamp value to change each time an update is made to the user's account?

Comment: What do you mean by "but this isn't working". In what way it isn't working?

Comment: The security stamp is not changing in the database.

Comment: Have you refreshed database?Do you use asp.net core scaffolded identity?Then it has a `SecurityStamp` colum in `AspNetUser` table. I test and it works well since Security Stamp is a random value that must change whenever a users credentials change (password changed, login removed)https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.identity.identityuser-1.securitystamp?view=aspnetcore-2.2

Answer (score 2):

That is what happens. However, the security stamp is only re-validated on an interval (every 30 minutes, by default), to reduce the number of database queries being made. You can lower this interval, even to zero, which effectively makes the stamp be re-validated with each request. However, that will increase the chatter back and forth to the database.

```
services.Configure<SecurityStampValidatorOptions>(o =>
{
    // WARNING: this will issue a query for every request
    // You might want to rather just compromise with an interval
    // less than 30 minutes (5 minutes, 10 minutes, etc.)
    o.ValidationInterval = TimeSpan.Zero;
});
```

An alternative option is to simply log the user out after such a change. If the goal is to simply make them re-login, that should do the trick much better. Just inject `SignInManager<TUser>`, and then call `SignOutAsync` on that instance. You'll need to redirect the user afterwards. That could be directly to the sign in page or to some area of the site that is protected, which will then cause them to be taken to the sign in page to authenticate. In either case, a redirect is necessary to have the auth cookie actually be deleted.

Comment: Hi Chris. Where does this go in the solution? UserManager? Startup?

Comment: Sorry. That would go in `Startup.ConfigureServices`. Thought the `services` variable would have conveyed that, but I should have been more explicit.

Comment: I don't think this is working. It's still not updating the field in the database. i changed a user's password and security stamp for that user is still NULL.